# How to read 1-bit unformatted Fortran binary data?

Tags: python, binary, fortran

I want to read numerical model output file in Python. 
This model output file is unformatted Fortran output file.

So, to read in Fortran

```
OPEN(10, FILE=FILE_NAME, STATUS="OLD", ACCESS="DIRECT", FORM="UNFORMATTED", RECL=NX*NY, CONVERT="big_endian")
```

and to write other format(NetCDF), output format is `f8(float)` format.

I'm trying to read the 1-bit binary file in Python,
(`fromfile` function in the NumPy module, struct module, etc..)
but I am getting the wrong data or read error.

Comment: So, in Fortran you can read that data with this `open` statement, and you want to know how to read the same data in python? What do you mean with "1-bit"? Is that file storing booleans?

Comment: Yes, I want same data in python. but, I'm trying to read binary in python, reading data is different.

Comment: @Daniel When editing first posts please try to fix as many problems as possible including spelling, capital letters and grammar (depending on your English skills), especially if your edits still have to be approved by reviewers.

Comment: @wxmin You must show your Python code and your error nessages, otherwise your question is likely to he closed. Also show how the Fortran data is written, not just how the file is openned. Don't forget the file is bigendian.

Comment: It's been a good while since I used FORTRAN but back then, I remember that unformatted data was record-structured by the FORTRAN runtime library (i.e. was not a simple Unix/Linux binary stream). So reading it correctly using Python may involve reverse-engineering your runtime library and may be dependant on the particular FORTRAN compiler and platform in question.

Comment: DIRECT access should not have any record structure.  You can sanity check that of course your file size should be precisely the data size.   @wxmin what is the type declaration for the data in fortran?

Comment: Since you're using CONVERT= I am going to guess that you are using Intel Fortran. Keep in mind that in Intel Fortran, RECL is in 4-byte units for unformatted files (unless -assume byterecl is set.) There is no record structure to this data. I suggest doing an "od -h" of the file to see what the structure actually looks like.

Comment: RECL=NX* NY would imply 1-byte, and often a LOGICAL is 4-bytes. So dumping a logical arras could be RECL=NX* NY* SIZEOF(Logvariable(1,1)). It is possible to shove those own by a factor of 32, into bits; but it seems like a lot of work.